# how to access html input type text in code behinde c# in grideview

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {            
                 $("#tb1").datepicker($.datepicker.regional["de"]).datepicker("option", {
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
        });


    </script>



<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Birth Date" SortExpression="BirthDate">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                   <input type="text" id="tb1" style="width: 150px" name="tb1" runat="server" >

                </EditItemTemplate>
```

in code behind I  tried to set the value of tbCalender in Editing mode

```
((HtmlInputText)GvClient.Rows[nrow].FindControl("tb1")).Value = textbox1.ToString();
```

the problem is the javascript datepicker is not fire when I click on the tb1 text.

Comment: did you check in console if it has the same id when your grid is in edit mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that server-side HTML controls are assigned a unique ID when they are rendered, so that ID in your JS isn't the ID of your rendered HTML element.

Change your `$("#tb1")` selector to use a jQuery 'endswith' selector:

```
$("[id$='tb1']")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ant P is almost right about the server side controls being given a unique ID but not all server controls have different ID and unique ID.

Simple controls like a server side text box or button normally have the same ID and unique ID unless they are being used in a dynamic control like a grid view. Because the grid view is bound to a data source and will generate its rows dynamically it cannot assign its children a specific ID, the ID will be generated dynamically and is accessible through the UniqueID property of the control.

So I suggest to find the unique ID pattern of your control (the dynamically generated input) by debugging your output HTML and then use the right regular expression pattern to get it.

Hint: The unique ID will contain the ID attribute that you specify in your source code.

Answer (score -1):

For get property of node, u can use..

```
$("tb1").attr("name_attr");
```